# Como hago que el cut salte de linea en un While

Tags: shell-script

hoy me he encontrado con el problema de que no soy capaz que coja linea a linea el while read linea, lo que neceisto es que me los corte linea a linea. y actualmente cuando corta me los da todos juntos.

Aqui os dejo lo que tengo actualmente:

```
while read linea
do
  usuario=$(cut -c "1-9")
  echo $usuario
done < llistat1.txt
```